# php binary and system timestamp strange difference

Tags: php, linux, timezone

I just encountered strange difference in php binary timezone output, what may cause this ?

```
[root@s19445807 ~]# php -r 'echo date("H:m:s"). "\n";'
17:01:54
```

while system time is:

```
root@s19445807 ~]# date
friday, 27 January 2017 17:34:42 +0100
```

The system time zone is `Europe/Berlin` as well as php.ini settings:

```
[root@s19445807 ~]# php -i | grep 'php.ini'
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/lib
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/lib/php.ini

[root@s19445807 ~]# cat /usr/local/lib/php.ini | grep timezone
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
date.timezone = Europe/Berlin
```

system timezone :

```
[root@s19445807 ~]# date +'%:z %Z'
+01:00 CET
```

Comment: The format character for minutes is `i`. `m` is two-digit month. It being January, no surprise you're seeing `01`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as `cHao` said the issue was in incorrect `m` modifier `echo date("H:m:s")` should be `echo date("H:i:s")` and also i had reintalled `tzdata` package and everything went well